# Value changed in finally ignored in try block

Tags: java

In the following code snippet, the value of j changed to 20 in the finally block is ignored and the original value of 10 is returned.

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i=testMethod(10);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int testMethod(int j){
        try{
            return j;
        }finally{
            j=20;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return j as 20 then put the return statement after the finally block instead of in try block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finally` is executed after the *entire* `try` block completes. That means, in this case, `j` has already been read and is about to be returned. `j` will not be re-read after it is assigned in the `finally` block, so the assignment has no apparent effect.

Comment: So what would happen if the `j=20` was replaced with a `return 20`?

Comment: @Lagerbaer 20 would be returned in that case.

Comment: So basically any kind of assignment operation is redundant inside the finally block is it?

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick Unless it's a global variable or you're re-reading the variable later in the `finally` block.